# Robot framework - examples from google docs not working

Tags: java, python, jython, robotium, robotframework

I have just begun working on Robot framework (just started learning Python as well..) . Whenever I try to run some code examples from google docs, it throws me various errors. Now, I apologize for my ignorance, bit I want to know where I am going wrong. 
Ex: 
I copy this code from google code, but it doesnt work.

```
:FOR    ${var}  IN  @{VALUES}
Continue For Loop If    '${var}' == 'CONTINUE'
```

What should my values/var variables contain to make it work. It always throws a "NOT a keyword Exception". I have not installed Jython BTW. Do i have to install it?

Also, how can I use the "CALL METHOD" keyword.

```
Call Method ${hashtable} isEmpty
```

doesnt work. Even if I initialize hashtable to some val or set it to none.

EDIT :

```
TC 01
     FOR    ${item} IN  @{list}
       Log  ${item}
```

I am trying to run the above code. I have defined both list and item (i think declaring item as variable is unnecessary, correct me if i am wrong). Now when I try to run this code, I am getting 'For' is a reserved keyword error. If I try to inser a '\' before LOG or FOR, it says - "No KeyWord WITH name '\FOR' FOUND." . What am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Robot Framework you don't need Jython, it is just an option. Python is all you need.

Your for loop is not valid, it should be like this:

```
*** Variables ***
@{list}           foo    bar    lorem    ipsum    dolor    sit    amet

*** Test Cases ***
Example
    : FOR    ${item}    IN    @{list}
    \    Log    ${item}
```

If you save that as an `example.txt` and run `pybot example.txt` in the same directory, it passes and logs all items of `list` individually.

In order to use `Call Method` you need to have some object with methods to call. So you must have a python file which has a class, function and have that class instantiated and assigned to a variable. Like this:

```
class MyObject:
    def __init__(self):
        self.args = None
    def my_method(self, *args):
        self.args = args

obj = MyObject()
```

and save that to `vars.py` (same directory as `example.txt`) and then put this in to your `example.txt`

```
*** Settings ***
Variables         vars.py

*** Variables ***
@{list}           foo    bar    lorem    ipsum    dolor    sit    amet

*** Test Cases ***
Example
    : FOR    ${item}    IN    @{list}
    \    Log    ${item}

Example2
    Call Method    ${obj}    my_method
    Should Be True    ${obj.args} == ()
    Call Method    ${obj}    my_method    arg
    Should Be True    ${obj.args} == ('arg',)
    Call Method    ${obj}    my_method     a1     a2
    Should Be True    ${obj.args} == ('a1','a2')
```

But my guess is that you don't really want to use `Call Method` at this point.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But what do you mean by-"Your for loop is not valid, it should be like this:". I copied the code snippet of for loop from google docs. Nevertheless, I agree with you. the syntax i have used is not making any sense to me.

Comment: `:FOR    ${var}  IN  @{VALUES}
Continue For Loop If    '${var}' == 'CONTINUE'` means that the FOR loop does not contain any keywords. You need to put `\    ` before the `Continue For Loop If` keyword.

Comment: It works now...My syntax was wrong. "SPACING" error from my side. One question, why are we using "\". What purpose does it serve?

Comment: Please read the example I gave you. Especially pay attention to the for loop and the line after it. It is not `FOR`, it is `:FOR`. And the line after it start with \ and at least two space characters. Why do we need to put the `\    ` in there? Because that is the syntax. Why did  Pekka Klärck (http://stackoverflow.com/users/38083/pekka-klarck), inventor of Robot Framework, settle for such a syntax? I don't know.